# How to test Exchange Server -2003 credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I have been developing a program to test whether the user given credentials of exchange server-2003 like user name,password, domain name, server name are correct or not.

If the above said credentials are correct, then I will be allowing them to send/receive emails.

Please let me know the method/code to test to complete the above said operations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ? any error messages/exceptions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have LDAP Access to the domain, you can just use System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry and bind to LDAP://domain/RootDSE using the credentials provided. If it succeeds, the credentials are ok.

If you know the Exchange server, you can just try to access the mailbox root folder (http://exchangeserver/exchange/primarymailaddress).

Of course you need the primary mail address of the user.